# Error: "httpd.conf: module auth_basic_module is built-in and can't be loaded" apache ubuntu on ec2 instance"

Tags: apache, built-in

I have an ec2 instance with ubuntu 12.04 installed. I am trying to upload a running server application on this instance. The application requires JBoss 4.0.4 and apache 2.2.3 to run. The application is old, therefore I can not use the latest JBoss and Apache 2. I installed JBoss 4.0.4 and apache 2 but ran into difficulty configuring it. So I uninstalled Apache 2, downloaded apache 2.2.3 and installed it...now when i try to run the command "**/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl start**" (old version of apache is installed in apache2) to start apache i get this error "**httpd.conf: module auth_basic_module is built-in and can't be loaded" apache ubuntu on ec2 instance**".

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like Apache was built by including modules in the code its self rather than having them loaded during startup.

Comment out the line in httpd.confwhere it is trying load this module(s)

You might try httpd -M  to see a list of already compiled in modules.